# Social network for bike users

Tags: touring

Does a social network exists for bicycle users?

I'm working on a website that caters bikers who want to discover some parts of France, and I'd like to allow bikers to share their experience. I could use FB, but some other soc net are maybe more relevant.

What would a biker do?

Comment: Perhaps some mapping communities, such as Bikemap.net, or even Ridewithgps.com, but I'm not sure about their full feature set.

Comment: I love the social parts of Strava.com (Kudos, Segments, Clubs, Segment leader boards) but they do not offer a way to really communicate in text (other than ride comments).

Comment: Have you looked at [Adventure Cycling](http://www.adventurecycling.org/)?  They have some forums on their site, and a lot of other information, links, and contacts.

Comment: Have you chatted with the [OCD](http://www.ocd.org.uk/)?  "OCD stands for 'Ordre des Cols Durs' - 'the club of the hard cols' - a French cycle club of which we are the British-based English language equivalent. OCD Cycloclimbing acts mainly as an information exchange for cyclists who enjoy cycling in the mountains."  They have invaluable maps and trip reports for Alpine and Pyrennaean tours and could really use a decent web presence.

Comment: [Google+](https://plus.google.com/u/0/communities) has a bunch of communities, pages and circles around different aspects of bicycling. I mostly follow the [Bike Commuter Cabal](https://plus.google.com/u/0/113243588894759116291) circle and the [Bike Commuting](https://plus.google.com/u/0/communities/101791526784396691991) community, but I'm sure there's some touring things around, too...

Comment: It's a forum, but [Bikeforums.net](http://www.bikeforums.net) pretty much fills this function.

Comment: For the moment, Strava is the closest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Warmshowers](http://www.warmshowers.org/) is certainly not a "social" network in the meaning of socializing only on the internet. But it is an internet-organized network for socializing with other cyclists in the real world. Certainly a good fit to this question's tags `touring` and `social`. It's a great opportunity to meet really nice and interesting people - highly recommended!

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK the biggest social network for bicycle riders is [www.pinkbike.com](http://www.pinkbike.com/) which has:

```
Over 200,000 users, riders and friends on Pinkbike.com!
```

although the ["friend finder"](http://www.pinkbike.com/user/list/) currently reports:

```
593,662 users
```

Comment: I was rather looking for a site that caters tourers rather than mountain bike…

Answer (score 2):

[BikeForums.net](http://www.bikeforums.net/forum.php) is a fairly active community with a wide range of topics around cycling.  There is a regional section which goes down to the [European level](http://www.bikeforums.net/forumdisplay.php/243-Europe).

Answer (score 0):

[Crazy Guy on a Bike](https://www.crazyguyonabike.com/), while not a social network, has some extremely active forums. While Bikeforums is much larger, since you commented that you're primarily interested in touring, you'd do well to check out CG.